# Replacing open bracket character in a C/C++ macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

I need a macro to pass the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to a function which has default arguments. This has opened up a can of worms, since default args with macros are either not possible or very messy, and I need to support both GCC and MSVC if possible:

```
class Class
{
#ifdef _DEBUG

   int Function(int a, int b = 10, int c = 20) { return a + b + c; }

#else

   int DebugFunction(const char* filename, int lineNo, int a, int b = 10, int c = 20)
   {
      printf("%s (%i) a:%i b:%i c:%i\n", filename, lineNo, a, b, c);
      return a + b + c;
   }

   //Not possible
   #define Function( DebugFunction(__FILE__, __LINE__

#endif
}
```

I've tried \escaping the ( to no avail. The codebase is huge, so fixing up the missing default args or creating multiple macros isn't a popular option.

Any solutions?

Comment: Why did you say "since default args with macros are either not possible or very messy"? This isn't true and isn't relevant to your problem. I think you just want a simple way to automatically prepend `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to certain function calls. Is this your goal?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was trying (and have now succeeded to) achieve. KerrekSB's solution worked a charm. I think in my head I was making this more complex than it should have been.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a variadic macro:

```
#define Function(...) DebugFunction(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Since you cannot "overload" macros, this might be your best bet.

Comment: How could I count the number of args passed in? I still need to substitute the args NOT passed for some default values.

Comment: @Catch33: You can't, and you just don't bother. You'll get a compiler error anyway if you use it wrong. (But of course ttd's solution is much better.)

Comment: I don't get it - you don't get a compiler error for using the variadic macro wrong, it's a runtime hell. If there was only one arg in the list, I can't pull 3 args out...

Comment: @Catch33, just use the standard default-args functionality in C++. `void foo_(const char * file, int lineno, int x, int y=3, int z=5)` and `#define foo(...) foo_(__FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)`. Is there something I've misunderstood?

Comment: If the user calls the function like:

foo(12, 20);

That's only two args passed in. I need to make up for the rest of the args. The compiler wouldn't explicity expand the macro to include the missing (default) args.

Comment: @Catch33, macros don't work the way you think they do. Just try it. It will work with or without the default arguments :-)

Comment: +1. Just be aware that this will only work until you decide one day that `a` also gets a default value.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well I'm a little embarrassed and I owe you an apology - that worked just fine. I've been doing my research all day (several resources say that default args with macros aren't possible) without actually trying that...

Comment: @Catch33: Don't be embarrassed; I too thought that variadic macros behaved like variadic function arguments. I learned something new today. That's why I love this site so much.

Comment: @EmileCormier I've read, and re-read the articles I'd based my original replies on, and it's clicked - default args INSIDE THE MACRO DEFINITION aren't possible. Inside the function I'm trying to replace, that's a different story, and this example works a treat for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @JensGustedt - Noted. I'm positive that won't be the case for the real-world code I plan to use this in, though, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @JensGustedt: When that happens, you can use the GCC extension `DebugFunction(__FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)`, or you pull in some dastardly Boost preprocessor magic.

Comment: @KerrekSB, your first idea doesn't work for all the compilers the OP mentions, and the for the second, to my disappointment, he asked for a solution without that, preprocessor magic.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Well... it's all hidden behind a nice veneer of Boost polish. Have you seen `BOOST_OPTIONAL_COMMA`?

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to rewrite your main function `Function` like this:

```
int Function(const char* filename, int lineNo, int a, int b = 10, int c = 20)
{
   #ifdef _DEBUG
       printf("%s (%i) a:%i b:%i c:%i\n", filename, lineNo, a, b, c);
   #endif
   return a + b + c;
}
```

That way, all the calls go to the same function, but the behavior of that function depends on whether or not you have the `_DEBUG` flag set.  This bypasses the issue of default arguments, since you just have a normal function call with conditional code inclusion rather than a macro that might need many arguments.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Haha, the simplest solution is often the best!

Comment: Simple yet effective, but I'm afraid it wouldn't be popular among the team since it means a giant find/replace on a huge codebase, and also enforces them to write (__FILE__, __LINE__ everytime they make use of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do, but would a [variadic macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) do the trick?

Comment: Along the right lines, but I couldn't count the number of vari-args passed in to choose the correct macro

Comment: Yup, turns out I didn't need to count the number of args at all. See KerrekSB's reply.

Answer (score 1):

Not a big c++ guy, but have you tried something like (in pseudocode)

```
#ifdef debug

#define Function(args) _Function(__file__, __line__, (args))
int _Function(char *file, int line, args) { /* code */ }

#else

#define Function(args) _Function(args)
int _Function(args) { /* code */ }

#endif
```

The function itself needs to be able to take multiple versions of arguments, of course; I don't really see any other way of doing this.

Comment: Again, along the right lines, but I can't count the number of args passed in

Comment: @tbert: For this to work, I think `Function` would need to be invoked like this: `Function((arg1, arg2, arg3))`.

Comment: @Catch33: I'm unsure what you mean by "count the number of args"? are you missing my "in pseudocode" comment above?

Comment: @Catch33 have edited a portion I missed before; apologies for any unclarity

Comment: @tbert: The pseudocode looks logical but doesn't work in practice - there are DEFAULT arguments in the function definition, these aren't accounted for when the macro is expanded. If I only pass in one argument, when I pull the rest from the (args) list they would be garbage.

Comment: @tbert: I was not attacking you, I was providing extra relevant information to help the OP (and others who'll stumble on this post) find a solution. :-)

Comment: @EmileCormier: didn't think you were, was just clarifying :)

Comment: @Catch33: then I think you might be hosed, sir; unless you can get some version of #define Function _Function(__file__, __line__, (args)) working, I think you may have hit upon a place where "want" and "possibility" fail to intersect.

Comment: @tbert - Turns out this sample was correct. I've been making it a lot more complicated in my head than it should have been, and now I see that the articles that say default args in macros aren't possible simply mean default args INSIDE macros aren't possible. Thanks for the help!